# SimpleModal Contact Form with multiple email addresses on same page

Tags: php, javascript, simplemodal

I have a contact page with 5 different email addresses e.g. info@domain.com, jobs@domain.com, feedback@domain.com etc... Ideally I would like each link to open a different version of contact.php that is customized specifically for that address. I'm sure there must be a way to transfer a variable (contact_info.php or contact_feedback.php) from the link to the contact.js to load the appropriate php file. Any help would be awesome.

Many thanks for that Eric. I ended up doing the following

```
<a href='#' id="info" class='contact'>info@thedomain.com</a>
<a href='#' id="jobs" class='contact'>jobs@thedomain.com</a>
```

in the contact.js I changed the link to the following:

```
// load the appropriate contact form using ajax
$.get("data/contact_"+this.id+".php" , function(data){
```

I then saved each contact_*php accordingly

Live page can be found here http://www.nashi.com.au/contact.html

Comment: Many thanks for your help Eric & your great script

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify, I'm assuming you are using the Contact Form Demo.

One suggestion:

1) assign an id for each contact link:

```
<a href="#" id="info" class="smcf-link">More Info</a>
<a href="#" id="jobs" class="smcf-link">Jobs</a>
```

2) Modify the `contact.js` file to pass the ID to the contact.php file:

```
$('#contact-form input.contact, #contact-form a.contact').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // load the contact form using ajax
    $.get("data/contact.php?id=" + this.id, function(data){
        // create a modal dialog with the data
        ...
    });
});
```

3) Modify the `contact.php` file to receive the id and processing accordingly:

```
$token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";
$id = isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : "";

// do whatever you need to do based on the value in $id
```

You could create different php files (and change the JS accordingly), it's up to you.

-Eric